# How to query for a snapshot by field that had a specific value?

Tags: javers

The following query returns changes to `Subscription` entities whose `status` field *changed* within the date range.

```
 QueryBuilder.byClass(Subscription.class)
             .from(LocalDate.of(2017, 11, 1))
             .to(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 1))
             .withChangedProperty("status")
```

How can I write a query that finds historical versions of `Subscription` that had a certain `status` on a given date? I'm not looking for changes to `status`, but just want to find the snapshot of the entities who had a particular status on a given date.

Something like:

```
javers.findSnapshots(
     QueryBuilder.byClass(Subscription.class)
                 .on(LocalDate.of(2017, 11, 1))
                 .withProperty("status", "TRIAL"))
```

This would return snapshots of `Subscription` where the `status` property was equal to `TRIAL` for the last commit starting from 2017-11-01 backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there is no such option, we have the open issue for that, see https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/556